# Email about a job in a completely unused tag

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I received an email from the Stack Overflow Jobs site this morning, with the heading and subject:

> We really like this job for you

This particular job has only two tags, the first of which I've never interacted with on Stack Overflow. (Perl and jQuery - I have interactions in jQuery but nothing in Perl.)

I would suggest that the job matching algorithm needs a tweak! Half of its tags being irrelevant should be a strong enough signal not to feature this job in an email.

Comment: If it's not personal, would you consider adding the tags the job included? (It'll help flesh out why this case clearly felt "off" from a user perspective.

Comment: @Jaydles sure thing, duly added.

Comment: I, too, received a "hey, we like you for this job" ad that was a senior-level position for some framework I do use and Perl, or perhaps just Perl? I can't remember now, but definitely Perl was involved, and I do zero Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this email to our attention.  We're sorry for sending you an email featuring a job that's not relevant to you!

Since launching the "We really like this job for you" email, we've heard from a few people in situations similar to yours.  We're working on a way to automate determination of which tags *need* to match to send you the featured job.  For example, a job titled "Perl developer" should probably require the recipient to be associated with the [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) tag.

For those who don't know, you can edit your liked and disliked tags for Jobs purposes on your [Job Preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).  Look in the Technologies section for "Tech you want to work with" and "Tech you prefer not to work with."  You can also edit this section on your [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current) to the same effect.  Our job-matching algorithm takes these tags into account  if you have specified them.

Editing your tags wouldn't have solved the problem of receiving an irrelevant job match this time, unfortunately.  Again, though, we're working on making the matching better.  We're not quite to the point of *developing* the solution yet, hence the [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) tag, but it's definitely on our radar.

**Edit:** So, I guess this work *is* underway... updating to [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).